# Uncaught ReferenceError: test123 is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple paragraph which can show up or hide away, depends of current state, but I find trouble over and over - the console shows me message "Uncaught ReferenceError: test123 is not defined at index.html:17". This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.xxx {
      display: none;
}
</style>
<script> 
function show() {
    var xxx = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (xxx.style.display === "block") {
      xxx.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      xxx.style.display = "block";
    }
};
document.getElementById(test123).addEventListener("click", show());
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="test123">Test</h2>
<br />
<p class="xxx">This is a test paragraph, which can show up.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're passing a variable test123 to method getElementById, I see that you wanted to pass a string with value test123, so try to wrap your argument with quotes - it's gonna help to solve your error in the console

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example

```js
document.querySelector("#test123").onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector(".xxx").classList.toggle("hidden");
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#test123 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="test123">Test</h2>
<p class="xxx hidden">This is a test paragraph, which can show up.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really close, but there are a couple things happening at the same time.

1. Your script runs when your DOM is parsing, and the element cannot be found when the JS is running, because it does not yet exist.

   - I solved this by making the script the last part of the body
2. `document.getElementById` expects a string parameter, this could be a raw string like `"test123"` or a variable that is a string `var test123 = "test123";` either work fine.

   - I solved this by making it a string.
3. `nextElementSibling` was targeting your `<br>` and instead of the intended text.

   - I removed your `<br>` element because it isn't really necessary. [Read here about flow in HTML](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/guide-css-layout/).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .xxx {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="test123">Test</h2>

  <p class="xxx">This is a test paragraph, which can show up.</p>
  <script>
    function show() {
      var xxx = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (xxx.style.display === "block") {
        xxx.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        xxx.style.display = "block";
      }
    };
    document.getElementById("test123").addEventListener("click", show);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```